# Why expandtabs() in python working in weird way?

Tags: python-3.x

I just observed the `expandtabs()` string method in python is working in weird way that I cannot understand, I understand that it adds spaces but given the length its is working in different way. Can Anyone explain whats going on?

```
str = "this is\tstring example....wow!!!"

print ("Original string        : " + str)
print ("Defualt exapanded tab  : " +  str.expandtabs())
for i in range(-2,30):
    print ("Double exapanded tab   : " +  str.expandtabs(i) , i)
```

OutPut :

```
 Original string        : this is        string example....wow!!!
 Defualt exapanded tab  : this is string example....wow!!!
 Double exapanded tab   : this isstring example....wow!!! Length : -2
 Double exapanded tab   : this isstring example....wow!!! Length : -1
 Double exapanded tab   : this isstring example....wow!!! Length : 0
 Double exapanded tab   : this is string example....wow!!! Length : 1
 Double exapanded tab   : this is string example....wow!!! Length : 2
 Double exapanded tab   : this is  string example....wow!!! Length : 3
 Double exapanded tab   : this is string example....wow!!! Length : 4
 Double exapanded tab   : this is   string example....wow!!! Length : 5
 Double exapanded tab   : this is     string example....wow!!! Length : 6
 Double exapanded tab   : this is       string example....wow!!! Length : 7
 Double exapanded tab   : this is string example....wow!!! Length : 8
 Double exapanded tab   : this is  string example....wow!!! Length : 9
 Double exapanded tab   : this is   string example....wow!!! Length : 10
 Double exapanded tab   : this is    string example....wow!!! Length : 11
 Double exapanded tab   : this is     string example....wow!!! Length : 12
 Double exapanded tab   : this is      string example....wow!!! Length : 13
 Double exapanded tab   : this is       string example....wow!!! Length : 14
 Double exapanded tab   : this is        string example....wow!!! Length : 15
 Double exapanded tab   : this is         string example....wow!!! Length : 16
 Double exapanded tab   : this is          string example....wow!!! Length : 17
 Double exapanded tab   : this is           string example....wow!!! Length : 18
 Double exapanded tab   : this is            string example....wow!!! Length : 19
 Double exapanded tab   : this is             string example....wow!!! Length : 20
 Double exapanded tab   : this is              string example....wow!!! Length : 21
 Double exapanded tab   : this is               string example....wow!!! Length : 22
 Double exapanded tab   : this is                string example....wow!!! Length : 23
 Double exapanded tab   : this is                 string example....wow!!! Length : 24
 Double exapanded tab   : this is                  string example....wow!!! Length : 25
 Double exapanded tab   : this is                   string example....wow!!! Length : 26
 Double exapanded tab   : this is                    string example....wow!!! Length : 27
 Double exapanded tab   : this is                     string example....wow!!! Length : 28
 Double exapanded tab   : this is                      string example....wow!!! Length : 29
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python expandtabs string operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34546171/python-expandtabs-string-operation)

Answer (score 0):

- string.expandtabs(tabsize) method returns a copy of string with all tab characters '\t' replaced with whitespace characters until the next multiple of tabsize parameter.
- string.expandtabs(i) method returns a copy of string with i size replaced with whitesace characters.
- for string.exapandtabs(8) method has exactly 8 characters before so no space.
- for string.exapandtabs(9) method has exactly 8 characters before so 1 space and so on.